# Better setting of EDITOR environment variable to use Sublime Text 2 as system editor?

Tags: linux, bash, git, text-editors, sublime-text-2

I want to use Sublime Text 2 for editing Git commit messages. Right now I have the following in my bash rc file:

```
export EDITOR="sublime -nw"
```

This works well if Sublime is already running. But if it's not, Sublime starts up with *2* windows rather than 1: one for my Git commit message, and one with the project I was working on most recently. And before Git stops waiting for me to finish editing, I have to close *both* of those windows.

Is there a better way to set `EDITOR` which works around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question on StackOverflow about a year ago (and being told the question belonged on Superuser), I have come up with a setup which works really well:

- ~/.bin/start_sublime:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # this script ensures that Sublime Text is running

  if [ ! "$(pidof sublime_text)" ] ; then
    # start up an instance of Sublime
    "/home/alex/Downloads/programs/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text" &
    sleep 1 # avoid race condition
  fi
  ```
- ~/.bin/sub_new_block

This opens a new window, and waits for you to close *that window only*, not any other Sublime window which you may have had open. This makes it work just right for editing patches or commit messages in git, etc:

```
    #!/bin/bash
   /home/alex/.bin/start_sublime
   "/home/alex/Downloads/programs/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text" -nw $FILE
```

- ~/.bin/sub_existing_noblock:

This uses an existing window if there is one, and the shell does not wait for you to close the window:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    "/home/alex/Downloads/programs/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text" $FILE &
```

- ~/.bin/sub_new_noblock:

This always opens a new window, and again the shell does not wait for you to close the window:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    "/home/alex/Downloads/programs/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text" -n $FILE &
```

For general editing, `sub_new_noblock` seems to be the most useful variant, so I alias it as `sub`. For git, I use the following config: `git config --global core.editor sub_new_block`. For other programs which launch an editor, I configure them to use whichever script is most appropriate.